# Redirect to a spanish or english version of my rails app?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, geolocation

I have a rails app, with 2 version english and spanish version. Using I18n, what's the optimal way of determining the user's location and redirecting to the proper spanish or english version depending on where's currently based?

Perhaps google map API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think most of the users are not have positioning devices in their desktops and laptops so some time getting location using Google Maps API will fail.

best way is using the IP address.Get the user IP address and check which IP pool belongs to and you can determine the country.

Comment: determining the user's country or location is not he problem, the actual problem is knowing which is the default language (or main language) for each country. So you can actually know where do redirect.

Comment: do you have multiple countries ? .. except for english and spanish